# Carry flag addition instruction different to adc $0?

Tags: assembly, carryflag

Is the `adc $0` instruction the only way to add the `Carry Flag` to `%rdx` on x86/64?

```
add %rax,%rcx
adc $0  ,%rdx
```

Comment: There are related, but more elaborate ways, like zeroing a register and using that in place of the zero literal. There are others too. What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Its about learning other choices :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's the best way**.

The other options include using `jc` (to skip an `inc`), `cmovc` (probably with `lea` for a no-flags add-1), or `setc`.   With setc:

```
xor  %edi, %edi
add  %rax, %rcx
setc %dil         # %rdi = CF, since we already zeroed the upper bytes
add  %rdi, %rdx   # no partial-register stall/extra uop from reading rdi after writing dil, because we used a recognized zeroing idiom (xor) to zero it.
```

These options are obviously much worse, even though `adc` is a 2-uop instruction on [Intel CPUs before Broadwell](http://agner.org/optimize/).  (Since Haswell introduced the hardware changes for FMA to decode to a single uop, Broadwell and Skylake also handle some other 3-input instructions as a single uop, including `adc` and `cmov`.)

An even worse option for getting CF into a register would the slow rotate-with-carry `rcl` (on a zeroed register).